# syntax error in creating a table in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_TRANS = "Transaction";   
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TRANS = 
       "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_TRANS + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
       + "Amount text not null, " + "Name_of_bank text unique not null, " 
       + "Trans_Time text not null);";

 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            System.out.println("oncreate of dbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TRANS);
        }
```

while running I get the error:

```
 08-05 14:40:15.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5362):
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Transaction": syntax
 error: create table Transaction(_id integer primary key autoincrement,
 Amount text not null, Name_of_bank text unique not null, Trans_Time
 text not null);
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please can you learn how to format your code? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that "Transaction" is a key word that you are not allowed to use.  Try changing the name to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Care must be taken when using SQLite keywords as identifier names.As a general rule
of thumb you should try to avoid using any keywords from the SQL language as identifiers, although if you really want to do so, they can be used providing they are enclosed
in square brackets.
For instance the following statement will work just fine, but this should not be mimicked on a real database 
sqlite> CREATE TABLE [TABLE] (
...>   [SELECT],
...>   [INTEGER] INTEGER,
...>   [FROM],
...>   [TABLE]
...> );

here is a link for sqlite keywords

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

and here you can find naming conventions for databses

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/hip/us/hip_us_pearsonhighered/samplechapter/067232685X.pdf

Comment: Thank u... for ur reply and links , It was useful